# How to identify provider for oauth2 redirect_uri callback?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Im trying to undertand how to properly identify which provider a returning authorization request was initiated by. I see three approaches:

- Use provider specific `redirect_uri` callback URIs. `/oauth2/<provider-name>/callback` etc.
- Encode provider id/name in `state` parameter somehow
- Store a pending provider id/name in the web session
- Try to verify response with all used providers

I've read parts of the OAuth2 spec but I can't find anything discussing it. Looking at other client implementations it seems as provider specific URIs is the most common solution. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients may not be multi-tenant and are tightly integrated with a single Authorization Server, so there's no need to store a provider identifier because there's only a single fixed one. That may be the reason why there's no obvious solution.

Multi-provider clients like your's should store the provider identifier as part of the `state`. This is because the `state` should be protected, and the provider specific `redirect_uri` is not. One could play an access token for provider A against the callback for provider B and thus defeat the purpose of a provider specific callback.

`state` can be protected either by reference to server state or to an encrypted cookie, or by value in the form of a self-contained encrypted structured value for the state parameter, and thus can be a safe mechanism to store the provide identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm implementing OpenID connect so i'm reading up  on how OAuth2 works. By "play an access token" do you mean the code used with response type code? But in the case of OpenID connect is it ok to rely on the token validation? assuming you distinguish between the providers using state or different callbacks to know where to fetch the token and which shared secret to use.

Comment: Yes, In OpenID Connect one would identify (and verify) the Provider by looking at the `iss` claim in the `id_token`. Yes, when talking about the Basic Client Profile, the playback would be done with `code`, in the Implicit Client Profile it would be `access_token`.